# .NET MAUI TabBar Gradient

Tags: c#, maui

How do I add a gradient to the TabBar and make it look something like this :

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you posted is from (what I recall...) what iOS Spotify used to looked like over 8 years ago - it's kinda old-fashioned now - do you have a good reason for wanting to emulate such a dated look?

Comment: Afaik it's not possible to set a gradient as background for `TabBar`. You can only customize the background with a fixed color. If you need it you probably have to create a custom component to replace `TabBar`. You could open a proposal in MAUI repo with your request, too.

Comment: Well, triple no. Brushes are backgrounds, not colors. TabBar has color, not background. And even if it had background (like Shell.Background), it would still do nothing, because guess what: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10445.

Comment: But it seems a black background color in your picture.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT its got a transparent fade

Comment: If this can be achieved in the native android or ios, you can try to use the custom render or handler to do that.